# best way to get the difference between two containers of type map< classId, set< studentId> >

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following two containers

```
map <classId, set< studentId> > allStudents;
map <classId, set< studentId> > assocStudents;
```

where assocStudents is a sub-set of all students.
what is the most efficient way to get the difference of allStudents minus assocStudents to get unassocStudents?

```
map <classId, set< studentId> > unassocStudents;
```

the best I can think of is to

1. iterate through each class in allStudents, do a search of that classId in assocStudents.
2. if the class exists in assocStudents, do a set_difference of the studentId;
3. otherwise copy the whole studentId set.

is there a smarter way to do this?

EDIT:

I got a bit lost with the answers provided.

assume I have the following data

```
 allStudents contains classId 1, studentId {1, 11, 111, 1111}
                      classId 2, studentId (2, 22, 222, 2222}
 assocStudents contains classId 2, studentId {22, 2222}
```

I like the final container to be

```
 unassocStudents contains classId 1, studentId {1, 11, 111, 1111}
                          classId 2, studentId (2, 222}
```

wouldn't set_difference give me the following

```
 unassocStudents contains classId 1, studentId {1, 11, 111, 1111}
```

Comment: use `std::set_difference`

Comment: Have you tried `std::set_difference(allStudents.begin(), allStudents.end(), assocStudents.begin(), assocStudents.end(), std::inserter(unassocStudents, unassocStudents.end()))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you the answer that you want:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <set>

using classId = int;
using studentId = int;
using map = std::map<classId, std::set<studentId>>;

int main()
{
    map allStudents{
        {1, {1, 11, 111, 1111}},
        {2, {2, 22, 222, 2222}},
    };
    map assocStudents{
        {2, {22, 2222}},
    };
    map unassocStudents;

    // Setup keys.
    for (auto const& i : allStudents) {
        auto& unassocSet = unassocStudents[i.first];
        auto& assocSet = assocStudents[i.first];
        std::set_difference(i.second.begin(), i.second.end(),
                            assocSet.begin(), assocSet.end(),
                            std::inserter(unassocSet, unassocSet.end()));
    }

    for (auto const& i : unassocStudents) {
        std::cout << "classId = " << i.first << '\n';
        for (auto const j : i.second) {
            std::cout << "\tstudentId = " << j << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

[See it working here](http://ideone.com/eHszh8).

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)

```
#include  <iterator>

std::set_difference(allStudents.begin(), allStudents.end(), 
            assocStudents.begin(), assocStudents.end(),
            std::inserter(unassocStudents, unassocStudents.end()));
```

Comment: the problem I have is that set<studentId> may not be the same inside allStudents and assocStudents. Doing a set_difference assumes that set<studentId> is always the same.

Comment: After set_difference, you could iterate through `unassocStudents` and set_difference for `set<studentId>` individually

Comment: I don't see the problem. `set<studentId>` in assocStudents isn't a subset of `set<studentId>`in allStudents? If it is then the `operator<` of `std::pair` sorts it all out which does a lexicographical comparison.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested.
the following is the C++98 implementation of @Simple's solution

```
typedef map<int, set <long> > csMap;
for (csMap::const_iterator i = allStudents.begin(); i!=allStudents.end(); ++i){

    set<long>& assocSet = assocSet[i->first];
    set<long>& unassocSet = unassocSet[i->first];

    set_difference (i->second.begin(), i->second.end(),
                    assocSet.begin(), assocSet.end(),
                    inserter(unassocSet, unassocSet.end()));

    if (unassocSet.empty()) { unassoc.erase( i->first);}
    if (assocSet.empty()) { assoc.erase( i->first);}

}
```

@simple's C++11 solution

```
// Setup keys.
for (auto const& i : allStudents) {
    auto& unassocSet = unassocStudents[i.first];
    auto& assocSet = assocStudents[i.first];
    std::set_difference(i.second.begin(), i.second.end(),
                        assocSet.begin(), assocSet.end(),
                        std::inserter(unassocSet, unassocSet.end()));
}
```